# forensic disk image of randomly disconnecting disk

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I'm currently aquiring a disk image for data recovery, however the disk is malfunctioning and is randomly disconnecting during the acquisition.

I'm using the linux "dd utility" with conv=noerror,sync options. The disk is reconnecting with different /dev/sdX after approximately 10G of data copied.

I modified the disk path to use the disk UUID but the dd still produces I/O errors and skips some of the data.

I verified it by copying the data chunk at the location when the disconnect occurred and that data is not corrupted at that location.

Is it possible to tell dd to rewind back few megabytes and reacquire them when the disconnect occur? I also have encase and FTK available but I'm not sure if they can deal with this situation.

Comment: It would help to understand the problem if you listed ALL arguments used when running dd.

Comment: I suggest you take the drive to a data recovery company to get it repaired; they may even directly provide you with the drive's image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) is good for.

Comment: Thanks! I was eventually able to recover the data after it has been running for 5 days. ddrescue had a problem with disconnecting disk and throwing the error "input file disappeared", however it picked up correctly from the previous location after I re-executed the ddrescue command.